# Update yaml via bash

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

I would like to udpate a file config.yaml file by inserting some configuration parameters via bash.

The file to be updated looks like:

```
{
  "log": [
    {
      "format": "plain",
      "level": "info",
      "output": "stderr"
    }
  ],
  "p2p": {
    "topics_of_interest": {
      "blocks": "normal",
      "messages": "low"
    },
    "trusted_peers": [
      {
        "address": "/ip4/13.230.137.72/tcp/3000",
        "id": "fe3332044877b2034c8632a08f08ee47f3fbea6c64165b3b"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rest": {
    "listen": "127.0.0.1:3100"
  }
}
```

And it needs to look like:

```
{
  "log": [
    {
      "format": "plain",
      "level": "info",
      "output": "stderr"
    }
  ],
  "storage": "./storage",
  "p2p": {
    "listen_address":"/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/3000",
    "public_address":"/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/3000",
    "topics_of_interest": {
      "blocks": "normal",
      "messages": "low"
    },
    "trusted_peers": [
      {
        "address": "/ip4/13.230.137.72/tcp/3000",
        "id": "fe3332044877b2034c8632a08f08ee47f3fbea6c64165b3b"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rest": {
    "listen": "127.0.0.1:3100"
  }
}
```

so adding

- on the first level `"storage": "./storage",`
- and on the second level in the `p2p` section `"listen_address":"/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/3000",` and `"public_address":"/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/3000",`

How do I do this with `sed`?

For YAML to JSON editor checkout---[YAML to JSON editor](https://www.yamlonline.com/)

Comment: may I interest you in this link: [RegEx match XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2805305) Although yaml might not be as complicated as html, the principle I think applies. Pick a tool fit for the job. Bash to edit yaml and json files is a bad idea imho. Is python an option?

Comment: It would be nice if only done via bash, but if not possible then python can be an option.

Comment: `on the second level in the p2p section` - this is (almost) impossible in `sed`, and even it is possible, it is very, very hard to do. Are you *sure* this is a yaml file? Because [this validator available online](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator) can't parse it and it looks like a json file. To parse json use `jq` utility.

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON, so if it's valid JSON, it's valid YAML as well. I don't know what issue that validator has with it, but the snippet shown is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your YAML file is written in the JSON subset of YAML, you can use `jq`:

```
jq --arg a "/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/3000" \
  '.storage = "./storage" |
   .php += {listen_address: $a, public_address: $a}' config.yaml > tmp &&
mv tmp config.yaml
```